# How to find the cause of Oracle Database slowness?

Tags: database, oracle

I work in a corporate which processes high traffic transactions every second. Recently, we switched over from primary database to standby database which has same power as primary one during the night. After switchover, the database was working fine. However, in the morning, it suddenly received too much database writing pressure, almost caused a failure. Transaction message logging has slowed drastically. It lasted about 50 mins. I checked the SQL monitoring on EM. I noticed there was a query which executed about 50 mins exactly during the slowness. But the same query was executed after 5 mins for only 10 seconds. I suspect there might have been something else was working parallel which caused the slowness. The incident occurred about 3 days ago.

I want to know the exact cause of the incident. How do I find it?

Thank you in advance

Comment: FYI, Database writer processes may have caused the delay

Comment: Depending on the Oracle version, edition, and what options you have licensed, I would expect that the information you're after is in the AWR tables or in the Statspack tables.  Beyond that, however, there isn't enough information in the question to give any sort of meaningful answer.